# python's print function not exactly an ordinary function?

Tags: python

Environment: python 2.x

If `print` is a built-in function, why does it **not** behave like other functions ? What is so special about `print` ?

```
-----------start session--------------
>>> ord 'a'
Exception : invalid syntax
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> print 'a'
a
>>> print('a') 
a
>>> ord
<built-in function ord>
>>> print

-----------finish session--------------
```

Comment: This is Python 2.x, correct?  If so, please **update** the question and add an appropriate tag for the **exact** Python version.  In Python 2.x, `print` is **not** a function and your assumptions are incorrect.  Please **update** the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that in Python 2, `print` is not a function but a [statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

In all versions of Python, *almost* everything is an object. All objects have a type. We can discover an object's type by applying the [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) function to the object.

Using the interpreter we can see that the builtin functions [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) and [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) are exactly that in Python's type system:

```
>>> type(sum)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(ord)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

But the following expression is not even valid Python:

```
>>> type(print)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because the name `print` itself is a keyword, like `if` or `return`. Keywords are *not* objects.

The more complete answer is that `print` can be either a statement or a function depending on the context.

In Python 3, `print` is no longer a statement but a [function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#print).

In Python 2, you can replace the `print` statement in a module with the [equivalent](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) of Python 3's `print` function by including this statement at the top of the module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

This special import is available only in Python 2.6 and above.

Refer to the documentation links in my answer for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 5):

`print` in Python versions below 3, is not a function. There's a separate *print statement* which is part of the language grammar. `print` is not an identifier. It's a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The deal is that `print` is built-in function only starting from *python 3* branch. Looks like you are using python2.

Check out:

```
print "foo"; # Works in python2, not in python3
print("foo"); # Works in python3
```

Answer (score 1):

print is more treated like a keyword than a function in python. The parser "knows" the special syntax of print (no parenthesis around the argument) and how to deal with it. I think the Python creator wanted to keep the syntax simple by doing so. As maverik already mentioned, in python3 print is being called like any other function and a syntx error is being thrown if you do it the old way.